# Mean of item's sub-category, based on category column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In my dataframe are columns for item's category number, sub-category number and classification of the item, like in example below:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'cat_id': [5,5,5,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,7],
 'sub_cat_id': [0, 2, 4, 1, 3, 5, 1, 2, 1, 2,4],
 'class':['A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B']}
)

df
    cat_id  sub_cat_id  class
0      5        0        A
1      5        2        A
2      5        4        A
3      6        1        A
4      6        3        A
5      6        5        A
6      7        1        B
7      7        2        B
8      7        1        B
9      7        2        B
10     7        4        B
```

Then I want to know, what is the average number `sub_cat_id` items that class `A` contributes, and class `B`?

- obviously this must take into account how many `cat_id` does class `A` have, class `B` have?
- my `sub_cat_id` items are NOT numbered in sequence. For example, in class `A` `cat_id=5`, `sub_cat_id` does not have `1 & 3`, `cat_id=6` doesn't have `sub_cat_id 2, 4`. In almost all cases, this is how the items are distributed.

Comment: Can you please add the expected output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby` and apply any function you are interested in. Here is an example for the mean

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'cat_id': [5,5,5,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,7],
 'sub_cat_id': [0, 2, 4, 1, 3, 5, 1, 2, 1, 2, 4],
 'class':['A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B']}
)

df.groupby("class").apply(np.mean)
```

the output is

```
         cat_id    sub_cat_id
class       
A         5.5      2.5
B         7.0      2.0
```